# sql query building with query data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to tables who looks like this

Table1

```
User_ID(int)|comment(text)|gender(int)
```

so it could be like 1|bla bla|1

Table2

```
ID(int)|Username(text)
```

Now I want to build a query like

```
SELECT Table1.User_ID,Table1.comment,Table1.gender FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.User_ID=Table2.ID SELECT Username
```

Is something like that working? I hope my query is not that bad to understand. If thats working in one way or another, is it also possible to make some more joins?

First time I have to work with joins. I'm a bit irritated, most examples are a bit abstract,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just list every columns that you want to select after the `SELECT` statement, even if they come from joined tables.

```
SELECT Table1.User_ID, Table1.comment, Table1.gender, Table2.Username
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.User_ID = Table2.ID
```

You could have as many joins as you want:

```
SELECT Table1.User_ID, Table1.comment, Table1.gender, Table2.Username
FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1.User_ID = Table2.ID
    INNER JOIN Gender
        ON Table1.gender = Gender.id
```

Comment: and the join will select all fields in the table/row ?

Comment: @Johnny000, only the listed columns will be selected, for instance here only `user_id`, `comment`, `gender` and `username` columns will be selected.

Comment: and how can I get a specific field in the innerjoin i.e. if Table2 would have like 10 fields but I just want the field "username"

Comment: @Johnny000, well in that case just put the `username` field in the select statement. Only the listed fields will be selected.

Comment: Yes! `SELECT table2.username`, however if the column name is unique, you can just do `SELECT username`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes. You can access table 2 fields in select statement also.